# C# web application javascript alert in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I want to create a `Javascript` alert in an `asp.net` web application. But i can't able to create this. I post my partial code is here the script manager javascript alert not displayed. Please help me to show the javascript alert..

```
if (noofday > totalday)
{   

    // I want to display the confirm message box in this section   

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete');", true);
    if(true)
    {
        DataSet5TableAdapters.sp_inleaverequestTableAdapter TA = new DataSet5TableAdapters.sp_inleaverequestTableAdapter();
        TA.GetData(lbl_empcode.Text, lbl_empname.Text, lbl_dept.Text, txtfromdate.Text, txttodate.Text, Convert.ToString(noofday), ddlleavetype.SelectedItem.Text, Convert.ToString(totalday), txtreason.Text, ddlforward.SelectedItem.Text, " ", " ", " ", " ", lbl_date.Text);

        Send_Email(lbl_empcode.Text, lbl_empname.Text, txtfromdate.Text, txttodate.Text, noofday, ddlleavetype.SelectedItem.Text, txtreason.Text);
        clear();
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Request sent successfully. Go and watch your status..');</script>", false);
    }
    else
    {   
        //DO Something
    }
}
else
{
    DataSet5TableAdapters.sp_inleaverequestTableAdapter TA = new DataSet5TableAdapters.sp_inleaverequestTableAdapter();
    TA.GetData(lbl_empcode.Text, lbl_empname.Text, lbl_dept.Text, txtfromdate.Text, txttodate.Text, Convert.ToString(noofday), ddlleavetype.SelectedItem.Text, Convert.ToString(totalday), txtreason.Text, ddlforward.SelectedItem.Text, " ", " ", " ", " ", lbl_date.Text);

    Send_Email(lbl_empcode.Text, lbl_empname.Text, txtfromdate.Text, txttodate.Text, noofday, ddlleavetype.SelectedItem.Text, txtreason.Text);

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Request sent successfully. Go and watch your status..');</script>", false);
    clear();
}
```

Comment: Check this out,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779576/how-to-display-windows-form-messagebox-in-asp-net-web-application

Comment: I need a message box in web application not in windows app..

Comment: Answer for your question is in this link, see properly,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779576/how-to-display-windows-form-messagebox-in-asp-net-web-application

This is for web application only.

Comment: Calling it "MessageBox" is what is confusing to everyone (its an "Alert", but they should be able to read your code and see that).  Can I ask if you have tried a script debugger like Firebug or the Developer tools in IE? They may give you more insight into if this script is even being sent to the page (maybe its not going to these if condition branches).

Comment: Also, I would suggest that you explain how you expect the user to interact with the page to get to one of these conditions. The community may have an alternate solution if they better understand your needs.

Comment: The above code is run under a button click. In this button click i want a message box if its ok means do some action else means do some action.please help me to do this. Because i don't have knowledge in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you first try to figure out if the code you expect is being returned to the page.

There are few ways to do this, with the easiest being "View Source" on the page after your above code runs. If you can find that content in the page, you will know that the content is being returned to the page but not executed.

If you do not see the content when viewing source, then you have a different problem. Either control is being passed to another page, or its not actually going to the if condition you expect.

Once you understand where the problem originates from these two pieces, you can start to find what may be causing it.

It is also somewhat apparent that you may not completely understand how the web works. Given this set of code....

```
       ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete');", true);
            if(true)
            {
                DataSet5TableAdapters.sp_inleaverequestTableAdapter TA = new DataSet5TableAdapters.sp_inleaverequestTableAdapter();
                TA.GetData(lbl_empcode.Text, lbl_empname.Text, lbl_dept.Text, txtfromdate.Text, txttodate.Text, Convert.ToString(noofday), ddlleavetype.SelectedItem.Text, Convert.ToString(totalday), txtreason.Text, ddlforward.SelectedItem.Text, " ", " ", " ", " ", lbl_date.Text);

                Send_Email(lbl_empcode.Text, lbl_empname.Text, txtfromdate.Text, txttodate.Text, noofday, ddlleavetype.SelectedItem.Text, txtreason.Text);
                clear();
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Request sent successfully. Go and watch your status..');</script>", false);
            }
```

... it appears that you are expecting the page execution on the server to stop and then wait for the client to respond. This is not how the web page life cycle works. The server code is going to execute completely and send content back to the client. Its not an interactive process (even with AJAX) like a windows forms or console application.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is problematic at best, especially if you are using VS 2003 like we are. Maybe it's better with VS2008 or newer versions of the Dev Suite. So we switched to a modal dialog for our popups. It was done using JavaScript. We used the subModal examples found on some of the older dev sites. Can't wait to rid ourselves of VS2003 and VB.Net. Yuck!

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you to you `Modal Pop` extender (`Ajax` Tool) instead of using `MessageBox`.
because `asp.net` does't contain `MessageBox`.

Comment: he is using a javascript alert.